# Check request.POST on pre_save in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, post, django-models, request

I have a pre_save.connect called in models.py which sends an email with the required data.

```
def send_comp_email(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
  eval = Evaluation.objects.get(id=instance.evaluation_id)
  ...
  msg.send()

pre_save.connect(send_comp_email,sender=eScore,dispatch_uid="send_email_uid")
```

This works fine, but I want to do a check to see if '_email' is in request.POST.

```
**if request.POST.has_key("_email"):**
```

But I need to pass in request.  How can I pass it into models.py?  I'm tired and keep getting errors.

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to within a signal. Why not do that on your view?

Comment: As you have the instance to be saved passed into the pre_save handler, you can try to attach `_email` info right on the instance in the view.